# Can't upload input into mysql database using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to upload simple user entered text from an input box to a mysql database using ajax and php. The idea is that after pressing 'display' the text can then be retrieved from the database and displayed on the page.

For an idea of what I am trying to achieve here is the HTML:

```
    <input type=text id="newjotting"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sumbit">
    <input type="button" id="display" value="Update Display">
    <div id="grabjottingsdiv">Jottings go here.</div>
```

The database and table 'jottings' has been created already. When 'submit' is clicked, this javascript is executed:

```
    function newjotting()
    { var newjot = document.getElementById("newjotting").value ;
      var jotURL = "line=" + newjot ;
      Ajax("POST", jotURL, "api/addjot.php", function(data){});
     document.getElementById("newjotting").value = "" ;
    }

    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(data){ newjotting();});
```

Using this Ajax function:

```
    function Ajax(method, value, URL, callback)
    { var ajaxObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ajaxObj.open(method, URL, true);
      if (method == "POST")
         { ajaxObj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); } ;
      ajaxObj.onreadystatechange = function()
              { if (ajaxObj.status == 200)
                   if (ajaxObj.readyState == 4)
                      callback(ajaxObj.responseText);
              };
      ajaxObj.send(value); 
     }
```

Which is supposed to send it to this php:

```
    <?php

   $hostname = "localhost" ;

   $username = "root" ;

   $password = "" ;

   $option = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) ;

   $_DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=ds6", $username, $password, $option) ;

   try {

       $newjotting = $_POST["line"] ;
       $q = "INSERT INTO jottings( jotting) VALUES (:newjot)" ;
       $query = $_DB->prepare($q) ;
       $query->bindValue(":newjot", $newjotting);
       $query->execute();

   $_DB = null

   }

    catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();

    }

   ?>
```

I've tried lots of changes with the php with no success. I'm starting to think it's likely a problem with the Ajax but I'm not sure what to try. Before anyone asks, I'm not supposed to use jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked for errors? Look at the browser's console for JavaScript errors.

Comment: In Firefox I get no error. In Chrome I get the error "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." but have no idea what this means.

Comment: For some reason, Chrome thinks you're trying to make a Synchronous AJAX call, instead of Asynchronous. On the face of it, I'm not 100% sure why, because at first glance, your code looks to be calling XMLHttpRequest() with the 3rd parameter set to true, which should tell it to be asynchronous. I haven't tried to run your code in a browser though.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I shall do some research on that and see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I believe it was because I needed to execute $q as opposed to $query. It's always the small things...